# How can I get a JSON response instead of XML?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, content-type

I just create a new WebApi project and keep the default controller :

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{ 
    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    //other services...
}
```

When I try to request it, I can't get a valid JSON result.

- No specific header => `application/xml` result
- Header with `content-type` assigned to `application/json` => `application/xml` result
- Header with `accept` assigned to `application/json` gives me a correct response `content-type` but a malformed JSON : `"value"`.

What is the way to get a valid JSON result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use [`JsonResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) as your return type:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{ 
    // GET api/values/5
    public JsonResult Get(int id)
    {
        object returnObject;

        // do here what you need to get the good object inside returnObject

        return this.Json(returnObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    // other services...
}
```

Comment: The problem is that a string is not automatically serialized. So, your solution is good.

Answer (score 3):

> - No specific header => application/xml result
> - Header with content-type assigned to application/json => application/xml result

Are you using MVC 4 RTM?  The default format should be application/json if you are using MVC 4 RTM...  I am unable to repro your scenario.

> - Header with accept assigned to application/json gives me a correct response content-type but a malformed JSON : "value".

"value" is actually a valid JSON value for string.  If you are looking for the format of a name/value pair, here is an example.  Say I have a class called 'Person' ...

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

... and I have a action that returns a person object,

```
    public Person Get()
    {
        return new Person() { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
    }
```

then the call to the above action will return this:

```
{"Id":1,"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, MVC4 RTM. I confirm that it works with an object. My problem is for a simple string. My Json parsers don't recognize "value" as a valid json string.